# Select whitespace from first line only using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I would like to match and substitute whitespace that appears in the first line of a CSV.

For example I want to substitute whitespace from the first line only with '_':

```
"product id","Region","Region Code" 
"888","North America","GEO123"
```

To give:

```
"product_id","Region","Region_Code" 
"888","North America","GEO123"
```

This is my current approach:

```
f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('newfile', 'w')

for line in f1:
  f2.write(re.sub('([\s])+', '_', line))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Which replaces all whitespace throughout the document. How can I adapt this so that it only works on the first line of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\s` also matches the newline at the end of the line. Better don't replace that! And no need to do so much yourself.

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('newfile', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(re.sub('[ \t]+', '_', next(f1)))
    f2.writelines(f1)
```

Thanks to `with`, you don't need to close the files yourself (read about "context managers" if you're interested). And the `writelines` replaces your looping.

Comment: awesome, what if I want to perform multiple regex operations at the same time? E.g. replace commas with pipes | and apply the above regex ?

Comment: @pele88 You *could* do that with one regex, but while *matching* different things is trivial, specifying the right *replacement* would require a replacement function rather than a simple replacement string. I'd just do two nested `re.sub`. You could also use the `replace` method of strings, or if you have *many* one-to-one translations, the `translate` method of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate function.

```
f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('newfile', 'w')

for i,line in enumerate(f1):
  if i == 0:
    f2.write(re.sub('[\t ]+', '_', line))
  else:
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: `if i == 0` doesn't sound quite idiomatic :)

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('newfile', 'w')

first_line = f1.readline()
f2.write(re.sub('([\s])+', '_', first_line))
for line in f1:
  f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty (and untested), and borrowed from Stefan's answer:

```
import re
with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('newfile', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(re.sub("[\ ]+", "_", f1.read().strip(), f1.read().split("\n")[0].count(" "))
```

Comment: `"[\ ]+"` does the same as `" +"`.